# Laravel unary relationship on join table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm running on Laravel 5.1

Currently I'm facing a problem which relation to `SELECT` query in unary relationship.

I have a `Category` model. It has attributes: `id`, `parent_id`, `name`.

I want to perform a search function which filter by the *category name* and *parent category name*.

I have this query

```
public function index($parent_id = 0)
{   
    $query = Category::select('category.*');

    if (\Input::get('q')) {
        $q = \Input::get('q');

        $query->leftJoin('category as parent', 'parent.id', '=', 'category.parent_id')
            ->where(function($query) use($q) {
                $query->orWhere('category.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                    ->orWhere('parent.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                ;   
            }); 
    }
    $query->where('parent_id', $parent_id); // update Nov 19, 2015 16:31
    ...
}
```

From this script, I got error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'parent_id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `category` left join `category` as `parent` on `parent`.`id` = `category`.`parent_id` where `category`.`deleted_at` is null and (`category`.`name` LIKE %q% or `parent`.`name` LIKE %q%))
```

Any idea how to put another **alias** to the current table *(not parent)*?

Comment: can you generate raw, let us tweak that, and then run that new raw?

Comment: @Drew I realize there is a where condition I forgot to put the table name in front of the column. Now working fine

Comment: you agree we can close this for reason of Typo ?

Comment: @Drew sure, you can close it

Answer (score 1):

I realised that there is a `WHERE` condition I didn't put in the table name.

```
$query->where('category.parent_id', $parent_id);
```

After I put in `category.`, now it works fine.